# Initiator nodes in a distributed system

Tags: java, operating-system, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I've got an assignment to find out the all possible initiator nodes for a state recording algorithm in the distributed system.

The question that has been given exactly is

> "Write a program to find out the all possible initiator nodes for a state recording algorithm in a distributed system.".

I want to mentioned that we have studied Chandy - Lamport's global state recording algorithm on our course of distributed operating system. I wrote a code for Chandy - Lamport's global state recording algorithm for the another assignment.

What does this initiator node signifies? I thought that those nodes who have recorded their corresponding states. Am I right? I've to write the code in java. Please suggest me the approach or an algorithm to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page on the [Chandy-Lamport algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandy%E2%80%93Lamport_algorithm):

> The assumptions of the algorithm are as follows:
>
> - There are no failures and all messages arrive intact and only once
> - The communication channels are unidirectional and FIFO ordered
> - There is a communication path between any two processes in the system
> - Any process may initiate the snapshot algorithm
> - The snapshot algorithm does not interfere with the normal execution of the processes
> - Each process in the system records its local state and the state of its incoming channels
>
> The algorithm works using marker messages. Each process that wants to
>   initiate a snapshot records its local state and sends a marker on each
>   of its outgoing channels. All the other processes, upon receiving a
>   marker, record their local state, the state of the channel from which
>   the marker just came as empty, and send marker messages on all of
>   their outgoing channels. If a process receives a marker after having
>   recorded its local state, it records the state of the incoming channel
>   from which the marker came as carrying all the messages received since
>   it first recorded its local state.

You are using slightly different terminology to the Wikipedia description, but I assume that your "nodes" correspond to the "processes" in the above.  Thus an "initiator node" is a simply a node that initiates (requests) a snapshot.

If that is what your terminology means, then with the Chandy-Lamport algorithm, any node could be an initiator node.  Hence the answer to the question is "all of them".

But, given the trivial nature of the answer / solution, I suspect that is not what your assignment really means.  Either you have left out some context, or the assignment is misstated.  I suggest that you ask your instructor.

(Or ... maybe it is a "trick question".)